# defined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::where()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am novice to CI and from documentation i have put the code but i am still getting an error...

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::where() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Nalanda_Library\application\models\SuperUserlogin.php
>   on line 8
>   my model code is like these

```
class SuperUserLogin extends CI_Model{
public function checkinglogin($username,$password){
    $password = md5($password);
    $username;
        $array=array('admin_username'=>$username,'admin_password'=>$password);
        $row=$this->db->get('admin')
             ->where($array);

        if($row->num_rows()){
            return $row->row->admin_user_id();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Remove this line that does nothing `$username;`

Comment: what should it return ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CI's `get_where()` [method](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html).

`$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);`